# How to handle dates in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

How to handle dates in GAS?

My form is using JQuery datepicker and I need to insert the chosen date in a cell and that date plus one month on another.

This is what I tried:

```
  //var datepicker=form.datepicker;
  var datepicker= new Date(form.datepicker);
  //var datepicker=Date.parse(datepicker);
  //var datepicker=datepicker.toString();
  //var datepicker=parseInt(datepicker);
  //var datepicker=datepicker.toDateString();

   sheet.getRange(2, 1).setValue(datepicker);
   sheet.getRange(3, 1).setValue(datepicker+1);
```

Which is returning:

```
1970/01/010
Invalid Date1
```

Although the selected date is 02-12-2014﻿

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

- I think you need to construct the date properly, you're referencing the datepicker object, which isn't a date, so get the date out of it. Try: `new Date(form.datepicker.getDate().getTime())`
- You can't 'plus one' to a date object. Call setMonth instead (it's range-proof). Try this: `date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+1)`

Comment: Thanks for your help. On the 1st point of your code, I get the error: TypeError: Cannot find function getDate in object 02-12-2014.

Comment: Well you didn't post all your code, so I had to guess. Get debugging :)